# Empty String vs NULL value in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to insert a document in elasticsearch. Some of the fields in document can be null. So should I store them as null or as empty string?

I just want to know the pros and cons of storing it as null vs empty string.

**NOTE** : I don't have to run any queries on those fields which are null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to run any queries on those fields, one good way is to use static mapping and just don't index them but if you have some use-case where you don't need to search on these fields but still want them to be part of your index, you can use the [store param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html) and choose to not `store` them.

This way these fields will still be part of `_source` which stores fields as it is(for ex: if you pass `null`, it will be `null`) and you can later retrieve them.

Regarding the pros and cons, we need to understand your use-case before commenting on them but my answer talks more on how to do it differently and optimize.

**Note:**, refer [null_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html) to understand concept in details.